# Looking-up part of text in a column and if found true pass a Creating a new column by reflecting assigned text value instead of true or false

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create categories based on particular string of keyword found true than assigned category else "other".

For example - if "health" is found in a column, name that keyword row as "HEALTH", if "therapist" then 'THERAPIST'

1. create a "category" column through code
2. assign categories based on condition

I was able to do on Excel by creating a table and using index match and want to switch to Python to apply this on large dataset,

**Below is the sample data**,

| keyword | category |
| --- | --- |
| HR Consultancy UK-d-uk-159_bing | other |
| it support COMPANY LONDON-D-UK-G1161_bing | other |
| global sales training platform openings | sales |
| tele private practice therapist | therapist |
| asset grant management system | other |
| digital team project management solution openings | other |
| global training platform openings | other |
| tele practice therapist | therapist |
| global sales training platform openings | sales |
| tele health practice | health |
| asset grant management | other |
| digital team project management solution | other |

Comment: do you have an exhaustive list of categories? What should happen if both "health" and "therapist" are present?

Comment: I am aware of this issue where some cell had two categories and excel used to pass one first based on sorting order. I don't have a solution for this right now.  I wanted to multiple categories in such case. But don't know how to achieve that. Let me know if you have solution for this. Would be really great.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I provided a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with all your keywords. Then, depending on whether you want to get the first match or all, use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) or [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with aggregation, respectively.

I added the keyword "*private*" as example to see a difference in row 3:

```
import re
words = ['health', 'therapist', 'sales', 'private']
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, words))
# 'health|therapist|sales|private'

# option 1: get first match
df['category_first'] = (df['keyword']
 .str.extract(f'(?i)({regex})', expand=False)
 .fillna('other')
 )

# option 2: get all matches
df['category_all'] = (df['keyword']
 .str.extractall(f'(?i)({regex})')
 [0].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
 .reindex(df.index, fill_value='other')
 )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                              keyword   category category_first       category_all
0                     HR Consultancy UK-d-uk-159_bing      other          other              other
1           it support COMPANY LONDON-D-UK-G1161_bing      other          other              other
2             global sales training platform openings      sales          sales              sales
3                     tele private practice therapist  therapist        private  private,therapist
4                       asset grant management system      other          other              other
5   digital team project management solution openings      other          other              other
6                   global training platform openings      other          other              other
7                             tele practice therapist  therapist      therapist          therapist
8             global sales training platform openings      sales          sales              sales
9                                tele health practice     health         health             health
10                             asset grant management      other          other              other
11           digital team project management solution      other          other              other
```

Comment: This works great!!! And answers my query. 

Just an addition question, this also shows same word twice in "category_all" if say keyword has "b2b cloud to cloud service" it returns result as cloud,cloud.

Comment: In place of `.agg(','.join)` use `.agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))` or `.agg(lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))` if order is important

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be

```
import pandas as pd
df = your dataframe
```

assigning the default value first. You could set to None, or np.nan too

```
df['category'] = 'others'
df.loc[df.keyword.str.contains('therapist'),'category'] = 'therapist'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pandas has apply methods for this:

```py
def f(s):
    if s.find('health')>=0:
        return 'health'
    if s.find('thera...')>=0:
        return 'thera'
    ...

df['category'] = df['text'].apply(f)
```

Read:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

2. pandas has map methods for this. First create a dictionary and then use map methods.

```py
d ={keyword1:category1, ...}
df['category'] = df['keyword'].map(d)
```

This is for when you have a specific dictionary.
Read:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: `apply` is certainly one of the worst ways to tackle this problem…

Comment: @mozway whats your opinion??

Comment: I would use a regex with a vectorial function

Comment: @mozway I always use apply method for similar problem and do not know your solve. If it is possible please learn me and write your solve

Comment: I'm waiting for OP to answer my question

Comment: Please when write your answer, tag me please on a comment

Comment: You can follow the question, then you'll get a notification on all new answers ;)

Comment: @AliM I also want to create a dictionary. I also made one kn in Excel and used to apply INDEX, MATCH function. But that is very slow in Excel.

Comment: @GIRIXH in pandas this is very fast
test it

Comment: yes, I will definitely try it. I way procrastinating using Python. Let's see what @mozway has to say. Will try it both ways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create first a list of keywords to test or research on it . Then the empty ones fill it with "other".

```
import pandas as pd

#example df
df=pd.DataFrame(data=['health xxxxx','yyyy therapist','zzzzz'],columns=["keyword"])

keywords=['health','therapist']


df['category']=df['keyword'].str.findall('|'.join(keywords)).apply(set).str.join(',')
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', "other")
```